# error retrieving template Job(deis-router@.service) from Registry in ec2 deis installation

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-cloudfront, deis

I'm trying to install deis in ec2 instance. I'm following the [deis documentation for ec2](https://github.com/deis/deis/tree/master/contrib/ec2#readme), but when I try to execute `make run` That gives the above error. Please can anyone help me?

Comment: could you please provide a gist of how you provisioned your cluster as well as the log output which shows this error?

Comment: How is that question related to Docker ?

Comment: @user2549135 please post your error code.

Comment: Deis is private PaaS using docker.

Comment: Don't gives any error code. I copied and past the error in here. Before this error it shows following line,
E0827 13:07:59.891706 71498 client.go:200] Unable to get result for {Get /_coreos.com/fleet/job/deis-router@1.service}, retrying in 100ms

Comment: @user2549135 are you sure that all deis services are runnig? please execute: `fleetctl list-units` to make sure. And verify if **router@1.service** are running.